# Dynamically fill @Html.DropDownList with numbers from 1 - x

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor-pages

In the view I have the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("numberup", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{Text = "1", Value = "1"},
    new SelectListItem{Text = "2", Value = "2"}
}, "Select NumberUp", new { id = "numberup", @class = "form-control", @style = "width: auto; margin: 0 0 25px 0;" })
```

I would like to create the select list items dynamically instead of typing them out one by one. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have an existing list of items? Or do you need a certain range of numbers? Please elaborate on the expected results for this list.

Comment: Like the title says I need to fill the drop down list with each select list item incrementing by one. The list text and the values need to be 1-30. I know there is an enumerable range but I do not want to use a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a `list` of `SelectListItem`s using `Enumerable.Range` and assign this to your `DropDownList`:

```
@{
    var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(x => x.ToString()).Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();
}

@Html.DropDownList("numberup", list, "Select NumberUp", new { id = "numberup", @class = "form-control", @style = "width: auto; margin: 0 0 25px 0;" })
```

HTH